# Сумма минимумов

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, вывод, перебор

Дан массив , в котором содержится  целых чисел. Нужно перебрать все пары чисел
 и  в этом массиве, для каждой пары найти минимум min(,  ) и сложить вместе все
эти минимумы.
Формат входных данных:
В первой строке записано целое число  — сколько чисел в массиве (1 <=  <= 300 000).
В остальных  строках записаны сами эти числа в том порядке, в котором они идут в
массиве . Все числа по модулю не превышают 10^9.
Формат выходных данных:
Нужно вывести одно целое число — искомую сумму минимумов .
Сумма  может быть довольно большой. Оценить максимально возможное
значение  и выбрать подходящий целочисленный тип.
Требуется решить задачу за время ().
**есть пока такая попытка, но это далеко не O(N):**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int A[300001];
    int N;
    int S; 
    S = 0;
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    for(int i=1; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d\n", &A[i]);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j!=i; j++){
            if(A[i,j]<=A[i,j+1])
                S=S+A[i,j];
            else
                S=S+A[i,j+1];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", S);
}
```

Comment: Нужно решить именно за `O(N)`, не за `O(N * log(N))`? C логарифмом задача бы принципиально упростилась: сортируем массив за `O(N * log(N))`, затем анализируем отсортированный массив за `O(N)`...

Comment: Да хотя бы с логарифмом. А дальше уже посмотрим, примет система тестирования или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ решения имеющий сложность `O(N * log(N))`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

int main(void)
{
    static int A[300000];
    int N;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);

    qsort(A, N, sizeof(int), cmp);

    long long sum_elements = 0;
    long long sum_type_a = 0;
    long long sum_type_b = 0;
    long long sum_type_c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        sum_type_a += (long long)A[i] * (N - 1 - i);
        sum_type_b += (long long)A[i] * (N - 1 - i) + A[i];
        sum_type_c += (long long)A[i] * (N - 1 - i) + A[i] + sum_elements;
        sum_elements += A[i];
    }

    printf("%lld\n", sum_type_a);
    printf("%lld\n", sum_type_b);
    printf("%lld\n", sum_type_c);
}
```

Тут выводится три суммы.
Первая сумма считается в предположении, что если мы учли пару `(A[i], A[j])`, то пару `(A[j], A[i])` учитывать не нужно. Также первая сумма не учитывает пары вида `(A[i], A[i])`.
Вторая сумма аналогична первой, но учитывает пары вида `(A[i], A[i])`.
Третья сумма аналогична второй, но учитывает обе пары `(A[i], A[j])` и `(A[j], A[i])`.
Не знаю, какую именно сумму вам нужно найти...

На входных данных

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Будет следующий [вывод](https://ideone.com/AWq2YN):

```
20
35
55
```

Comment: Первая сумма - как раз та, что нужно :) (без учета повторных пар и пар элемента с самим собой). Однако в тестирующей системе код не прошел. Причем не по времени, а просто на каком-то тесте получился неверный ответ. Посмотрю, может где недочет в подсчете

Comment: @A_Hatake, что нужно вывести, если в массиве всего один элемент? Не сам ли этот элемент? Приведённый код для одноэлементного массива выводит ноль.

Comment: В условии ничего про это не говорится. Но если подумать, то, скорее всего, просто вывести единственный элемент

Comment: скорректировала код, чтобы выводился единственный элемент, но все равно на каком-то тесте валится :(

Comment: Тест тот же самый или нет? Ещё возможно, что в массиве могут быть повторяющиеся элементы и их нужно убрать... Сейчас подправлю код.

Comment: тест тот же самый. Отрицательные элементы никак не могут влиять на это?

Comment: @A_Hatake, изменил код, попробуйте...

Comment: теперь код меньше тестов проходит. И все-таки, может в отрицательных элементах дело? или в слишком большом объеме данных в каком-то тесте?

Comment: похоже, что повторяющиеся элементы удалять не нужно. Уже не понимаю, в чем дело...

Comment: @A_Hatake, откатил изменения и исправил ошибку с переполнением, попробуйте ещё раз :)

Comment: Ура-ура-ура! Видать-таки, проблема была в переполнении, потому что задача принята. Огромное вам спасибо :)